# Why might I get expected: MappingNode was SequenceNode during kpt pkg get?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubeflow, kpt

I am undertaking https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/distributions/gke/deploy/deploy-cli/ and at the stage `bash ./pull-upstream.sh` there is a problem and I have isolated it to a single command inside the scripts:

`kpt pkg get https://github.com/zijianjoy/pipelines.git/manifests/kustomize/@upgradekpt upstream`

When I run this command alone, I get the same error as when it runs in the script:

```
Package "upstream":
Fetching https://github.com/zijianjoy/pipelines@upgradekpt
From https://github.com/zijianjoy/pipelines
 * branch            upgradekpt -> FETCH_HEAD
Adding package "manifests/kustomize".

Fetched 1 package(s).
Error: /home/tester_user/gcp-blueprints/kubeflow/apps/pipelines/upstream/third-party/argo/upstream/manifests/namespace-install/overlays/argo-server-deployment.yaml: wrong Node Kind for  expected: MappingNode was SequenceNode: value: {- op: add
  path: /spec/template/spec/containers/0/args/-
  value: --namespaced}
```

I made some mistakes following the script during the setup (that I think I corrected) so it could be something I did. It would be good to know why this error is happening even so for my general understanding.

I am on google cloud platform, in the command line prompt that comes built in to the web ui.